How to rectify this error
! LaTeX Error: File `pscyr.sty' not found.Type X to quit or  to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop. ^^M

Welcome to TeX.SE, please provide more details like what type of TeX engine you are using (e.g., MikTeX, or TeXLive, etc) and the version details, etc.

you've asked latex to load pscyr.sty, but don't have it installed. (for the record, it is not part of tex live, as far as I can tell.) either you have \usepackage{pscyr} somewhere or you are loading a package which does something similar. try commenting out that line and see if it works without that package.
